# Use Context not re-rendering child application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I created a project using CRA 2.0 with TypeScript. I am trying to use Context.

My end goal is to create a universal data store, where I have few items available. I am using typescript.

See the below code, My question is, I have a state in parent, I am setting it in state and passing it down. When I set state in parent (one with have context provider), It doesn't re-render the child component, so even after fetching new data, the context value stays same inside child unless I re-render child component.

```
Interface File (`interfaces/lookups.tsx`)

interface LookupItemInterface {
  value?: number;
  text?: string;
}

export interface LookupInterface {
  assessmentTypesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  billingPlansLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  categoriesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  competenciesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  emailTypesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  entitiesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  evaluationRolesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  questionTypesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  recommendedApplicationsLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  statesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  testTypesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
  userRolesLookUp: LookupItemInterface[];
}

export const lookupInitialState: LookupInterface = {
  assessmentTypesLookUp: [],
  billingPlansLookUp: [],
  categoriesLookUp: [],
  competenciesLookUp: [],
  emailTypesLookUp: [],
  entitiesLookUp: [],
  evaluationRolesLookUp: [],
  questionTypesLookUp: [],
  recommendedApplicationsLookUp: [],
  statesLookUp: [],
  testTypesLookUp: [],
  userRolesLookUp: [],
};

export interface LookupContextInterface {
  findByValue?: (id: number, key: string) => void;
  lookups?: LookupInterface;
}

export const LookupContextInitialState = {
  findByValue: (id: number, key: string) => {},
  lookups: lookupInitialState,
};
```

This is my context file (**LookupContext.tsx**)

```
import { LookupContextInitialState, LookupContextInterface } from '../interfaces/Lookup';

export const LookupContext = React.createContext<LookupContextInterface>(LookupContextInitialState);

export const LookupContextProvider = LookupContext.Provider;
export const LookupContextConsumer = LookupContext.Consumer;

export default LookupContext;
```

I created a container which I am wrapping my a template.

```
const LookupContainer: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const [lookupState, setLookupState] = useState({ lookups: lookupInitialState, loading: true });

  const errorContext = useContext(ErrorContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLookups();
  }, []);

  const findByValue = (id: number, key: string) => {
    console.log('find', id, key, lookupInitialState);
  };

  const fetchLookups = async () => {
    try {
      const newLookups = await getLookups();
      setLookupState({ ...lookupState, lookups: newLookups, loading: false });
    } catch (e) {
      setLookupState({ ...lookupState, loading: false });
      errorContext.setError(e, true);
    }
  };

  if (lookupState.loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return <LookupContextProvider value={{ findByValue, lookups: lookupState.lookups }}>{children}</LookupContextProvider>;
};
```

I am using Atomic Design Modal, and I am wrapping it on my Template for now.

```
const DashboardTemplate: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children }) => (
  <LookupContainer>
    <Sidebar />
    <Page>
      <TopBar />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </Page>
  </LookupContainer>
);
```

and finally, There's a container at down in children,

```
const TemplateContainer: React.FunctionComponent = ({ id }) => {
  const lookupContext = useContext(LookupContext);
  const {lookups, findById} = lookupContext; // <--- this will have initial context value unless I set state inside this and somehow re-render this

  const assessmentTypesLookUp = findById(id, 'assessmentTypesLookUp');
  return (
    <DashboardTemplate>This is Instrument</DashboardTemplate>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is a typo, but you are using `LookupContextProvider` which should either be `LookupContext.Provider` or you need a `const LookupContextProvider = LookupContext.Provider;` somewhere, which I couldn't find in your code.

Comment: This was a typo in question, actual code is fine. I updated the context file. This isn't the issue, I am sure about it.

Comment: Where are you rendering the `TemplateContainer` in your template?

Comment: Inside template container.